# Redirect domain name in HAProxy while preserving the URL path

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, haproxy

I have HAProxy as front layer to our Node.js app and I'm looking for a way to rewrite URL. For example, if customers go to `https://aaa.example/product/123`, HAProxy will rewrite to URL `https://bbb.example/product/123`. is this possible to do in HAProxy? The important is we want to preserve the URL path (`product/123`) and just change the host name.

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to "rewrite" but that is a term that is often misused.  What is your intention?

- Do you want to rewrite the incoming URL and then change the address in the browser's address bar with an HTTP redirect?

If so, in proxy configuration:

```
http-request redirect prefix https://example.org if { hdr(host) -i example.com }
```

This changes `example.com` to `example.org` and tells the browser to ask again.

Test:

```
curl -v https://example.com/foo/bar/1234?query=yes
...
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-length: 0
< Location: https://example.org/foo/bar/1234?query=yes
< Connection: close
```

This is the simplest solution if it fits your need, because the net result is that the browser is actually making the correct request itself, reducing the potential for unexpected behavior.

- Or do you want to change the `Host:` header that the backend server sees, but not send a redirect, and leave the browser's address bar as it was?

This changes `example.com` to `example.org` in the `Host:` header that the back-end server sees in the request from HAProxy.

```
http-request set-header Host example.org if { hdr(host) -i example.com }
```

This will do exactly what is intended, but it may not have the desired result, particularly if the application is aware of other inconsistencies, such as the incoming `Referer:` or `Origin:` being inconsistent with the `Host:`, or if it's doing non-portable things with cookies, in which case further header rewriting (possibly in both directions) or application changes may be necessary.

Comment: i want rewrite the incoming URL and then change the address in the browser's address bar with an HTTP redirect. I tried your suggestion but did not work. I wanted only `/product` do the redirection, so if customer request /cart it will not do redirection. I have tried following but did not work `http-request redirect prefix https://%[req.hdr(Host)]/product if { hdr(host) -i bbb.com/product }` . Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: `http-request redirect prefix https://example.org if { hdr(host) -i example.com } { path_beg /product }`  Note also that the `{` `}` must have at least one space between them and any adjacent character.  Don't use `%[req.hdr(Host)]` here -- that doesn't make sense, it's a routing loop.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: i am trying to redirect to remove the port from my URL. Can you take a look into this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418024/haproxy-remove-port-number-from-url