# Haproxy remove port number from URL

Tags: url, url-rewriting, haproxy

I have a backend trying to route traffic to a specific IP address and a port. The first hit on the url doesn't contain the port number. But the subsequesnt requests from within the website is not redirected properly.

Example: http://test.com has server 123.45.67.89:9080

When I try the URL http://test.com/login --> It is redirected correctly and I get the login page.

But once I give the login details and press OK. It is redirected to http://test.com:9080/loginSuccess.

The page is available under http://test.com/loginsuccess

This is the backend code and all the ways I have tried from different solution is commented.

```
backend lf_was_9080
   acl auth_lf_was http_auth(lf_was_auth_list)
   http-request auth realm lf_was_auth_list if !auth_lf_was
   mode http

   #TRY 1
   #http-request redirect prefix http://test.com/login if { hdr(host) -i test.com:9080/login }

   #TRY 2
   # Clean the request and remove any existing header named X-Rewrite
   http-request del-header X-REWRITE

   # Copy the full request URL into X-Rewrite unchanged
   http-request add-header X-REWRITE %[url] if { path_sub 9080/login }

   # Change the X-REWRITE header to contain out new path
   http-request replace-header X-REWRITE ^:9080/login(/.*)?$ /login\1 if { hdr_cnt(X-REWRITE) gt 0 }

   # Perform the 301 redirect
   http-request redirect code 301 location http://%[hdr(host)]%[hdr(X-REWRITE)] if { hdr_cnt(X-REWRITE) gt 0 }

   #TRY 3
   #reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /login/(.*)     \1\ /login/\2

   #TRY 4
   #http-request redirect prefix https://test.com if { hdr(host) -i test.com:9080 }
  server lf_was_9080 10.85.200.158:9080 check
```

I have also https redirect which works perfectly.

How can i rewrite the url without the port number in Haproxy?

Comment: First things, first... HAProxy isn't putting the port number in the URL.  If you can fix this via configuration of the actual system behind HAProxy, that's almost certainly the correct fix.

Comment: Otherwise, you might consider trying something along the lines of `http-response set-header location %[res.hdr(location),regsub(:9080/,/)] if { res.hdr(location) -m found }`.